# Sahi + PhantomJS fails when testing local PHP web app with behat

Tags: phantomjs, behat, headless-browser, mink, sahi

I'm having an issue testing a locally hosted web application with a behat+sahi+phantomjs set up.

- I have run the full suite with just behat+sahi+chrome which works fine
- I have also tested a small sample behat test against a live stie that works well

The issue appears to happen both when I point my base_url to either my locally hosted app or a server where that app has been deployed

Something as simple as this:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Get to the login page
        Given I am on "/login"
        And I should see "Email Address"
        And I should see "Password"
```

Results in this output:

```
Given I am on "/login"                     # FeatureContext::visit()
And I should see "Email Address"           # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
  Command execution time limit reached: `_sahi.setServerVarPlain('___lastValue___50ff0bcf186da', _sahi._getText(_sahi._byXPath("//html")))`
```

I'm using the setup detailed here: http://shaneauckland.co.uk/2012/11/headless-behatmink-testing-with-sahi-and-phantomjs/

Is this a configuration issue? Or because the app is also hosted on localhost?

What might I try to troubleshoot this further?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The issue appears to happen both when I point my base_url to either my
>   locally hosted app or a server where that app has been deployed

Phantomjs does not seem to use the proxy for localhost. You can try using your machine name instead. Are you sure it does not work for your server too? Is it possible to post more details to reproduce this?